# Which Shopify .liquid file should I insert a homepage modal into?

Tags: javascript, html, shopify, bootstrap-modal

I am using the Shopify .liquid theme "New Standard" for my site. I want to edit the html/css so that a basic modal displays on the homepage when the page has loaded.

I got the basic modal code from W3 and a javascript function so that it displays when the page is loaded. All of that works in my jsfiddle, I just do not know which .liquid file to include the code.

[.Liquid theme files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ZoUg.jpg)

Also, will the javascript be in a separate .liquid file than the modal?

Much thanks.

Here is my code:

```
{% if template == 'index' %}

<!-- Modal -->
    <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times; </button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
    <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
     $(window).load(function(){
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
  });
  </script>

  {% endif %}
```

[Block Element Modal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5BwxB.png)

Comment: See my proposed solution, let us know if it worked, and if it did, don't forget to give a credit.

Answer (score 4):

Put the modal code into a separate file called **snippets/modal.liquid**, then edit **layout/theme.liquid** and inject the following code before closing of the `</body>` tag:

```
{% if template == 'index' %}
    {% include 'modal' %}
{% endif %}
```

I would switch `$(window).load` with `$(document).ready` as well.
Don't forget to include Bootstrap JavaScripts and CSS in your template.

Answer (score 3):

If the modal is **only** going to show on your homepage, then you could put the code in the index.liquid file. This is your homepage's template file. You can also put the Javascript code in that file as well, however it's a better practice to place Javascript code towards the end of your `<body>`.

An alternative would be to put both the html for the modal and the Javascript in your theme.liquid file and place them inside of a conditional that would only load them if you are on the homepage. It would look something like this:

```
{% if template == 'index' %}
    <-- CODE FOR MODAL GOES HERE -->
    <-- CODE FOR JAVASCRIPT GOES HERE --> 
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried both approaches, but I am still having trouble. The modal is loading like a block element instead of a modal. I included my code and a picture above named "Block Element Modal".

Comment: Can you show me the jsfiddle that you set up where it is working?